# How can exoplanet moons be detected?

Tags: exoplanet, natural-satellites, satellite

How can exoplanet moons be detected? Are there current methods to differentiate exoplanets with moons and exoplanets without moons? Or, are only the combined masses of the exoplanet and its moons detectable?

Comment: Check out http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/how-to-find-exomoons/11133#11133